# converting float to str error: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, typeerror

In my data analyses a function returns a single `float value` or `tuple(float, ...)`. I want to `sum` it or convert it into `list` or `str` so I can sum it. But, whatever I try I am getting:

`TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

```
# For e.g
print('testing float errors')
ti = 0.236
print(ti)
print(type(ti))
print()

# all below three methods don't work. Why? And, what is the solution?
fi = [str(x) for x in ti]
fi = map(str(x), ti)
fi = sum(ti)
print(fi)
```

Comment: What is your expected output? You cannot iterate over a single value of `0.236`. Are you trying to iterate over the digits of that number?

Comment: Some are a single float, some are tuple of floats. I am trying to sum if multiple floats, else keep it as float. I am just trying to see why it's not working. At least I should be able to convert them to `str`, but I can't.

Comment: Use `str(ti)` for the first method, otherwise, you are trying to iterate over a floating point number, not a string.

Comment: Use: `fi = ti if isinstance(ti, float) else sum(ti)`.

Comment: `for x in ti` is trying to iterate `ti` - but it is a float, not an iterable.

Comment: @everestial007 People do not have to explain down votes on Stack Overflow. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s) explains why in more detail.

Comment: Your english is good enough, but the problem statement isn't. What are you trying to sum? What would you sum about a `str`? You should place an expected output for both your cases (`float` or `tuple` of `float`s). And your previous comment will certainly attract lots of downvotes. I too feel that downvoting is a too powerful tool in the hands of the brainless (which would use it whenever they don't understand a question, even if it was valid), but it's not the case here.

Comment: Ok, I'm working on it. I think the fact that you mentioned a string means that people are fixated on iterating over a string. I think that you want a float result, but your input is either a float value or a tuple of floats? Please give a few examples of valid inputs and their corresponding outputs.

Comment: @Crisri: I am not trying to sum the strings. But, if i can convert it to list of str and then float , then I can sum it. But, I cannot explain in better English than this.

Comment: Also, not every question should have expected output. I simply asked why am I getting type error in 3 different codes I tried. But, why downvote such question. To biologist (me) it's hard to program; but programming is an overrated trait. I wish this forum encouraged people but it's simply discouraging.

Comment: We could still do with some example data to confirm whether our answers are what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your Qs in order:

> I am trying to sum if multiple floats, else keep it as float. I am just trying to see why it's not working.

For the first part, to sum up multiple floats or keep it as a float, I would try something like this:

```
def sum_up(vals):
if isinstance(vals, tuple):
    return sum(vals)
return vals
```

To test:

```
print('Single float as a param: ',sum_up(0.236))
print('Tuple of float as a param: ',sum_up((1.23, 1.23, 0.2366)))
```

Output:

```
Single float as a param:  0.236
Tuple of float as a param:  2.6966
```

Second part, `I am just trying to see why it's not working.`:

```
# all below three methods don't work. Why? And, what is the solution?
fi = [str(x) for x in ti]
fi = map(str(x), ti)
fi = sum(ti)
print(fi)
```

None of the above would work because you cannot iterate over a single number and float is not iterable. The example of iterable would be tuple, list, or as clarified here what [iterable is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols#9884259)

If you would have changed `fi = [str(x) for x in ti]` with `fi = [x for x in str(ti)]` then you would have had a list of characters and you could manipulate it any way you like.
Next, `fi = map(str(x), ti)` change to something like `for e in map(str, list(ti)): ... # do something with e`. For the last piece `fi = sum(ti)` you need to convert the value of `ti` to iterable in order to call `sum()` on it. As [Azharullah Shariff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4907309/azharullah-shariff) proposed the solution above, it will help fixing it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot iterate a float, you need to use only

```
fi = str(ti)
```

But if you sometimes have a tuple of floats you can check it before with isinstance()

```
if isinstance(ti, tuple):
    fi = [str(x) for x in ti]
else:
    fi = str(ti)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have understood your requirement, I guess this is what you want to do:

Form a list of the characters in the float number and perform a summation of all the characters which are digits in it.

If yes, then doing this would solve your problem:

```
sum([int(x) for x in str(ti) if x.isdigit()])
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to test your input to see whether it is a `tuple` or not:

```
def sumOf(v):
    if not isinstance(v,tuple):
        v = (v,)
    return sum(v)

ti = 4.5
print(sumOf(ti))

ti = (2.3, 2.2)
print(sumOf(ti))
```

Output:

```
4.5
4.5
```

**Update:**

An explanation of your errors:

```
ti = 4.5
fi = [str(x) for x in ti]

    fi = [str(x) for x in ti]
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

The error is in the `for x in ti` part of the comprehension because `ti` is not iterable.

```
ti = 4.5
fi = map(str(x), ti)

    fi = map(str(x), ti)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

This is that `x` is not defined, so it cannot call `str(x)`.

```
ti = 4.5
fi = sum(ti)

    fi = sum(ti)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

The error here is that `sum` expects an iterable and you have provided a float.